# password reset link being sent as HTTP?

Tags: wp-admin, urls, security

I was just added as an admin on a WP site.
The first thing I noticed is that the "(re)set your password" link in the email starts with **http://**

How do I fix that? The "View Post" link in Comment moderation also uses HTTP, and possibly others as well (I haven't finished looking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is probably marked down as

http://youdomain
goto Settings and change 
WordPress Address (URL) 
from http://yourdomain to 
https://yourdomain
Site Address (URL)
from http://yourdomain to 
https://yourdomain